# More tag redundancy - phone models

Tags: support, tags, retag-request, tag-synonyms

We've got a lot of different tags referencing phone models: `droid`, `motorola-droid`, `incredible`, `htc-incredible`, `htc-droid-incredible`, `droid-x`, etc etc etc.  How do we want to unify these?

Answer (score 7):

My first thought with all of these is to err on the side of being a little verbose.  I like the format [manufacturer]-[model-name]: `htc-droid-incredible`, `motorola-droid`, `motorola-milestone`, etc.  That way phones with really short names don't get an ambiguous/confusing tag like `x`.

It does become a little unclear whether "droid" is officially part of the name for some models, though (for instance, is it the Incredible, or the Droid Incredible?)

Comment: I agree.  [manufacturer]-[model-name] sounds good to me and we can create synonyms from [model-name] to it.

Comment: Yes, "Droid" won't be sufficient as a tag as it's a whole family of phones by multiple manufacturers.

Comment: I would say the [Droid] tag should be a synonym for [Motorola-Droid].  All other Droid phones have some other additional name with it.  HTC Droid Eris, Motorola Droid 2 and X, HTC Droid Incredible, etc.

Comment: I agree with [manufacturer]-[model-name]. @Bryan: is there a way to make the [Droid] tag the [Motorola-Droid] to point to the same place, or are you just saying we should treat them the same?

Comment: @matt: Once you have 1000 rep, you can suggest synonyms to a tag, and vote on suggested synonyms.  I don't know what exactly happens with those, though... are new questions using the synonyms automatically re-tagged?

Comment: If you set up [Droid] as a synonym of [Motorola-Droid] then behind the scenes it will swap [Droid] to the [Motorola-Droid] tag, therefore condensing synonym tags into their parent tag.