# Merge device tag variations

Tags: discussion, synonym-request, retag-request

A lot of folks are using the [tmobile-g1](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tmobile-g1) tag to refer to the "HTC G1" ... presumably because the phone has no HTC branding on it and the tag exists so it seems reasonable (that's why I used it ...) Seems like both [tmobile-g1](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tmobile-g1) and [htc-dream](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/htc-dream) should be merged under a single tag that follows the "[manufacturer-model](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82/more-tag-redundancy-phone-models)" format.

I don't have the reputation to suggest tag synonyms but this seems worth addressing?

> Users with more than 1250 reputation and a total answer score of 5 or more on the tag, can suggest tag synonyms. Users with a total answer score of 5 or more, can vote for tag synonyms. Suggestions will be automatically approved when they reach a score of 4, and automatically deleted when they reach a score of -2.

I propose perhaps a community wiki here on meta to tease out all the poorly formed device tags and identify the correct tag they belong under.

Perhaps along the way we can do more re-tagging of posts with [inappropriate device tags](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260/should-we-discourage-phone-model-tags-in-non-phone-specific-questions) so that [new users](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/users/3550/amanda) don't look around, see a lot of bad behavior and model their own posts after folks who are doing it wrong!

Comment: Ha, crap!  I just went through and retagged everything with "t-mobile-g1" as "htc-g1" because I noticed the "t-mobile-g1" didn't follow the manufacturer-device standard.  Before I saw this question, I might add.  Great minds and all that...

Comment: Very nice, @Amanda. I'll make sure we have synonyms set up. One thing that will help is getting tag-wikis for those tags.

Comment: Also, you can use the "retag-request" tag here in meta to request retags if you don't have the rep to do it yourself.

Comment: Reminder: Vote for those synonyms! http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms

Comment: JonnyP and I don't have sufficient reputation to even view proposed synonyms.

Comment: Well, that's a bummer. But, considering your level of engagement here, I expect that limitation to be short-lived.

Comment: We should probably turn this into a community wiki rather than using the answers as a place to alert mods of errant tags we notice.

Comment: s/we/someone with suitable privileges/

Comment: Rather than one question for merge requests, I'd rather have separate questions. Like [this](http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/questions/98/merge-alarm-and-alarms-tags), [this](http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/questions/99/merge-widget-widgets), or [this](http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/questions/103/merge-android-market-market). Adding yet another answer runs the risk of being missed.

Comment: Okay: can we just close it? I just voted to close it. Alternatively, I can arbitrarily select an answer, which would be a nice thing for JonnyP since I can't select one of my own for two more days.

Answer (score 1):

[htc-g1](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/htc-g1) is a synonym for [t-mobile-g1](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/t-mobile-g1) and [htc-dream](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/htc-dream)

Comment: HTC Dream seems to be the original name for the device, it's just rebranded as T-Mobile G1. So I'll make htc-dream the main tag, with htc-g1 and tmobile-g1 as synonyms.

Comment: This is complete.

Answer (score 0):

[G2](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/g2) and [HTC G2](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/htc-g2/info) should be merged; It [sounds like](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/HTC_Desire_Z) both belong under [HTC Desire Z](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/htc-desire-z/info).

Comment: @Amanda: I don't think it's necessary to make these answers community wiki.

Comment: ok. I'm kind of done since I've disambiguated the phones that were bugging me (the G2 and the dream)

Comment: This will be trickier to disentangle. htc-g2 already has some synonyms.

Comment: At least merging G2 into HTC G2 (http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/htc-g2) would clear that up.

Comment: I think I have it cleared. You can see all of the proposed HTC Desire Z synonyms at http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/htc-desire-z/synonyms

Comment: HTC Vision is another name given to the G2. Though it appears to have been a pre-release name, so may not be used here on this site.

Comment: @thunsaker, I added the HTC Vision to the tag wiki for the device. I don't see any posts tagged "HTC Vision" so I don't think we need to add the synonym -- anyone with the device will know it by the names it was marketed under. For future reference, you, too can propose edits straight on the tag wikis.

Answer (score 0):

The [xoom](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/xoom/info) tag should be made a synonym of [motorola-xoom](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/motorola-xoom/info).

Comment: This one is done.

Answer (score 0):

There were three questions tagged `[galaxy]` which I retagged. Two were also tagged with `[samsung-galaxy-s]` and the third didn't seem to have relevance to the galaxy series at all.

I'm hesitant to suggest that `[galaxy]` should be a synonym of `[samsung-galaxy-s]` since there are other galaxy devices (and "galaxy" alone is really quite vague)...but it's one to consider, possibly, since that seems to be what many people mean when they just say "I have a galaxy" (or similar).

Comment: Nice. The "galaxy" tag should be killed -- it is meaningless. I believe you've accomplished that, however.  So there's nothing to merge here.

Comment: Yep, "galaxy" should be killed but not merged.  There are a lot of Galaxy 5 questions.