# How to handle iphone tags?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms

There are a handful of posts tagged with [iphone](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/iphone), [iphone-4](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/iphone-4), [ios](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ios), [ios4](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ios4).

Often the question is OS specific -- how do I migrate my contacts [to](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/751/how-to-get-contacts-from-an-android-phone-to-an-iphone) or [from](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/7358/how-do-i-transfer-iphone-contacts-to-a-android-phone) an iPhone -- or at least isn't about doing something with the iPhone device other than running the iOS on it.

Some are device specific ([can I install Android 2.2 on my iPhone 3G](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/664/installing-android-on-iphone-3g)) so they pass the [device tag test](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260/should-we-discourage-phone-model-tags-in-non-phone-specific-questions) even though they might also be redundant. Do they need revising to follow our [device tag model](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82/more-tag-redundancy-phone-models)? (apple-iphone-3g) or is iphone-3g sufficient? [iphone](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/iphone) is inadequately ambiguous.

How should these be tidied up?

Answer (score 8):

Since we're focused on Android, not iDevices, I don't think we need to be as "strict" about being very specific about devices or the distinction between hardware and OS.

I think the only tags we need are [iphone](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/iphone) and *maybe* [ios](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ios).

If the type of device is really that important to the question, then it seems to me that the question is probably off-topic.

By the by, some of the questions you're running into were migrated from the defunct gadgets.stackexchange.com. Android and iPhone were both on topic. Not sure if we should bother resurrecting those.

Comment: makes sense. seems like the right thing to do is to just merge all four tags under "iphone" and call it a day?

Comment: I think so, but let's see if someone else has an opinion.

Comment: I agree - keep it simple since we are focused on Android not iOS.

Comment: This sounds good to me.

Comment: This is done. I left "iphone" and "ios". The others are synonyms.

Answer (score 2):

I've merged [iphone](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/iphone) into [ios](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ios).  There wasn't a good distinction being made in their use and I don't think we've got all that many questions that were truly iPhone-specific.